# How to report to Google Analytics a navigate away?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Currently my application consists of the following:

1. Login page
2. Main page
3. Login page

The flow is as follows: From the login page the user is redirected to the Main page (using window.location.href change) everything is fine here. After that from the Main page the user click LogOut and they are redirected to the Login page (using window.location.href change).

Here is the problem: Once the user click LogOut a no response is sent to google analytics and it displays that the user is still on the Main page, the reality is that the user is redirected to the login page. The login page counter in GA (Google Analytics) is increased with 1 which right.
The problem is that the Main Page counter is not decreased by 1.

How can I explicitly tell Google Analytics that my user has navigated away from the Main Page?

I tried putting this in my Main page:

```
        ga('set', 'page', '/login.aspx');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The result is that the Main Page counter is decreased with 1, but the Login page is increased with 2 users.

Comment: I'm not sure you're quite grasping the concepts behind web analytics.  If a users lands on a page (for long enough that analytics is fired) then the view count for that page will increase by 1.  If they leave that page then you don't decrease that count because you would never have any users for that page then.  In web analytics there is no such concept to reduce the view count of a page.  If, of course, a user is on a page for such a short period of time that you do not want to register a view, you must make sure your GA code does not fire before the user moves on.

Comment: My idea is that Google Analytics is not implicitly detect that I am redirecting my user to an another page inside of the same application. That's why I think that I should notify GA any way for doing this redirection.

Comment: OK, so you need to make sure that your GA code that sends the pageview does **not** fire before the window.location.href statement that redirects your user.  You can stop tracking being fired, you cannot decrement it once is has been fired!  Good luck!

Comment: Actually my idea is not to decrease the pageview with 1, it is just to follow the natural flow of redirection and when the Login page is loaded, its own GA code to report that the user has been redirected to it.

Comment: I think something is being lost in translation here.  Just to clarify then: On the Login page (after a log out click) you're analytics is reporting the page the user is on as the Main page as opposed to the Login page?

Comment: It is reporting that the user is both on the Login and on the Main page.

Comment: When you land on the login page (after log out) look in your network debugger for calls to google-analytics.com?collect....etc - are there multiple pageviews being sent there?  If this is really the case then 2 pageviews will be seen, one for main and one for login.

Comment: If I remove the code snippet shown in the question from the Main page (execute just before log out) then the login page is increased only with 1, but the reporting dashboard shows that the user is still on the Main page as well.

Comment: Ahhh... so you're talking about realtime reporting in GA - i wouldn't worry about that, it takes sometime for the pages being shown to drop off.  As long as you're not seeing inflated numbers in core reporting then you do not have an issue.  This is just a quirk of realtime reporting.

Comment: Well, being honest I think that this issue that I am experiencing could augment the reported bounce rates. That's why I prefer to have it fixed. Also I have observed this Real Time dashboard and it seems that GA is not transferring my user from Main Page to the Login Page. It is just creating a new Login Page view instead.

Comment: Just looking at the dashboard is no good, you need to observe the actual HTTP calls being fired off from a page and see what is being sent.  If you're only send a single page call on the login page then GA will only record a single page call.  this is the only way to truly understand whats going on - don't even use a 'GA debugger plugin' or similar, observe the raw HTTP calls!